# Where did bash environment variable get initialized from?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

When I execute:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

on command line I get the following output:

```
/home/nehal/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-package‌​s:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/dist-package‌​s:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/dist-package‌​s:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/dist-package‌​s:/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/dist-package‌​s:/home/userx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/dist-package‌​s:/home/userx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/dist-package‌​s:/home/userx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/dist-package‌​s
```

I looked into `.bashrc` file and found only one `PYTHONPATH` set

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/nehal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-package‌​s:$PYTHONPATH"
```

I also looked into `.profile`, `/etc/environment` and `/etc/profile`
but nowhere could I find `PYTHONPATH`.

My question is where did the above extra paths come from?

Comment: There is a ``FILES`` section  ``man bash``, check it for list of files, but please note that it could change from distro to distro

Comment: See those `dist-packages`, and `site-packages` directories? Those are probably from when you installed ros and anaconda3.

Check and see what other files you are sourcing in your .bashrc

Comment: @nrb Is there a `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @NasirRiley No, Why?

Comment: @nrb Because depending on the environment, that file usually exists to initialize bash sessions as does `.bashrc`.

Comment: @NasirRiley Is it okay if the file is not present?

Comment: @nrb Yes, as long as there are other bash initialization files which it appears that there are. I was only wondering if there was a `.bash_profile` which might contain the other paths for `$PYTHON_PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

You can figure out which files are being sourced by tracing which files bash opens:

```
strace -e open bash -l
```

This should print out all the files bash tries to open (many of which are C libraries you can ingore).  That should give you hints about where to look. (The "-l" option to bash asks it to run as a "login" shell, which generally causes bash to parse a few more startup files.)

Answer (score 0):

On startup 'bash' loads it's settings from many files. Most of them usually live in subdirectories of '/etc' directory. So I would run the following command to find all files containing 'PYTHONPATH':

grep -R PYTHONPATH /etc 2>/dev/null